# How can I add watermark from Textbox to taken picture?

Tags: vb.net, image, textbox, windows-phone, watermark

How can I put the text from a TextBox on captured images ?
Is it possible to implement it to code from:
[Vb app code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using Bytescout.Watermarking SDK for .NET

Here's an example of code `Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports Bytescout.Watermarking
Imports Bytescout.Watermarking.Presets

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
' Create new watermarker
    Dim waterMarker As New Watermarker()
' Create new preset
    Dim preset As New TextFitsPage()
' Create new string
    Dim inputFilePath As String
' Create new string
    Dim outputFilePath As String

    ' Set input file path
    inputFilePath = "my_sample_image.jpg" '<-- place your captured image here
    ' Set output file path
    outputFilePath = "my_sample_output.jpg"

    ' Initialize library
    waterMarker.InitLibrary("demo", "demo")

    ' Add image to apply watermarks to
    waterMarker.AddInputFile(inputFilePath, outputFilePath)

    ' Set preset text
    preset.Text = "Bytescout Watermarking" '<-- place your textbox.text here

    ' Add watermark to watermarker
    waterMarker.AddWatermark(preset)

    ' Set output directory
    waterMarker.OutputOptions.OutputDirectory = "."

    ' Apply watermarks
    waterMarker.Execute()

    ' Open generated image file in default image viewer installed in Windows
    Process.Start(outputFilePath)

End Sub

End Module`
```

Source: [how to add a simple transparent watermark](http://bytescout.com/?q=/products/developer/watermarkingsdk/watermarkingsdk_first_step_with_visual_basic_net.html)

Comment: I've downloaded and tried Bytescount sdk, that works but its a demo...I need something like that but free and full.

Comment: Try this, it's very simple and it's without any library or external modules: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_watermark.html

Comment: Looks nice but how to change input watermark image to text from textbox ?

Comment: Look at this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-Add-Watermark-Text-to-Images-Photo-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: I think that all articles shows how to watermark existing image, I'm looking for code which insert text from textbox when I take a picture (on the fly) - text in textbox is not a constance.